# Two semantic elements being read as one

Tags: html, css, newline, element

(This is my very first time coding my own page - apologies if this seems obvious)

The layout of the webpage is: header, section.hero, section.middle containing an article and aside, section.infoform (a horizontal form) then the footer.

The issue is that although .middle and .infoform are separate sections the browser reads them as one, eg. if I change the background-color of one they both change. This also means that although I would like .infoform to display as a horizontal form on a new line it appears with its heading and first 2 boxes squashed in the right hand corner.

I've tried putting < br> after .middle and width:100% and display:block in the class and container of .inforform but none made any difference. I've also double checked that .infoform is not a child element of .middle.

Here's the code:

```css
.middle{
    display:inline-block;
}

article{
    float:left;
    width: 60%;
    font-size:30px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

article h2{
  font-family:'Prompt', sans-serif;
  font-size: 45px;
  color:#1C5C35;
}

article ul {
    list-style-image:url(images/bullet\ point\ dark\ green\ small.jpg);
    margin-left:20px;
}

aside div.stone_pic img{
    float:right;
    width:35%;
}

.infoform {
    background-color:#34A85C;
    color:white;
    font-family:'Prompt', sans-serif;
    font-size:30px;
    width:100%;
}

.container h3{
    padding-left:20px;
}

button{
    background-color:#F15A23;
    color:white;
    width:10%;
    border-radius:8px;
   }
```

```html
<section.middle> 

<article>
<h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque lectus arcu, blandit nec tellus et, auctor consectetur mi. Pellentesque sit amet neque sit amet sapien pulvinar varius. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla tempus pulvinar lacinia. Duis vehicula purus non est ullamcorper, at scelerisque velit pharetra. Sed rhoncus dolor nec volutpat convallis.  
</p>
<ul>
    <li>Example</li>
    <li>Example</li>
    <li>Example</li>
    <li>Example</li>
    <li>Example</li>
    <li>Example</li>
    <li>Example</li>
</ul>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque lectus arcu, blandit nec tellus et, auctor consectetur mi. Pellentesque sit amet neque sit amet sapien pulvinar varius. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla tempus pulvinar lacinia. Duis vehicula purus non est ullamcorper, at scelerisque velit pharetra. Sed rhoncus dolor nec volutpat convallis.  
</p>
</article>

<aside>
    <div class="stone_pic">
    <img src="images/stone_hose2.jpg" alt="side image-powerhose washing stone">
    </div>
</aside>

</section.middle> <br>


<section class="infoform" style="display:block; width:100%;"> 

<div class="container" style="display:block; width:100%;">
    <h3>Request a callback</h3>
    <form class="form-inline" action="/action_page.php">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"
            id="name" placeholder="Enter name"
            name="name">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
         <input type="email" class="form-control"
            id="email" placeholder="Enter email"
             name="email">
            <label for="tel">Tel:</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control"
            id="tel" placeholder="Enter phone number"
            name="tel" required minlength="11">
            <label for="service required">Service Required:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"
            id="service required" placeholder="Service required"
            name="service required" required minlength="11">
            <button type-submit>Submit</button>
       
    </form>
</div>

</section>
```

Just to note, as the image is not showing it looks as though the form is in a column next to the article rather than squashed underneath the image as it shows on the webpage.

Could someone more experienced suggest why the sections are not separating?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share what your CSS looks like for these elements?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I'm being a complete newbie here but will I need to repost my question to include a structured snippet? I'm not seeing the Markdown Editor option for my replies.

Comment: I believe the editor will always be able to accept markdown syntax. Try editing your post and surrounding the code with backticks like this: ``` Code Here ```

Comment: @BonChon You can edit your question by clicking Edit, just below your question's tags. Then click on the icon that has the angle brackets (< >) to add a stack snippet.

Comment: Thanks for putting the CSS in there. Would you mind showing where you declare your HTML Elements the same way? The problematic elements in particular

Comment: I've put the HTML and CSS in a structured snippet - as the image is not showing it looks as though the form is in a column next to the article rather than squashed underneath the image.

Answer (score 2):

### Problems

The main problem is this:

```html
<!-- This is incredibly invalid -->
<section.middle>...</section.middle>
<!-- This is what it should be -->
<section class='middle'>...</section>
```

Minor problems:

```html
<button type-submit>Submit</button>
<!-- Should be -->
<button type='submit'>Submit</button>
<!-- OR -->
<button>Submit</button>
```

id and name attributes should not have spaces.

Don't use `name="name"` it may cause unexpected behavior.

```css
.middle {
  display: inline-block;
}

article {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

article h2 {
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #1C5C35;
}

article ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

article ul li::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -5px 5px 0 0;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

aside div.stone_pic img {
  float: right;
  width: 35%;
}

.infoform {
  background-color: #34A85C;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container h3 {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

button {
  background-color: #F15A23;
  color: white;
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<section class='middle'>

  <article>
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque lectus arcu, blandit nec tellus et, auctor consectetur mi. Pellentesque sit amet neque sit amet sapien pulvinar varius. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
      Nulla tempus pulvinar lacinia. Duis vehicula purus non est ullamcorper, at scelerisque velit pharetra. Sed rhoncus dolor nec volutpat convallis.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>Example</li>
      <li>Example</li>
      <li>Example</li>
      <li>Example</li>
      <li>Example</li>
      <li>Example</li>
      <li>Example</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque lectus arcu, blandit nec tellus et, auctor consectetur mi. Pellentesque sit amet neque sit amet sapien pulvinar varius. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
      Nulla tempus pulvinar lacinia. Duis vehicula purus non est ullamcorper, at scelerisque velit pharetra. Sed rhoncus dolor nec volutpat convallis.
    </p>
  </article>

  <aside>
    <div class="stone_pic">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRl7jZZdRpUuiVUW7488MTU0-xqfzeCZU8Mtw&usqp=CAU" alt="side image-powerhose washing stone">
    </div>
  </aside>

</section> <br>


<section class="infoform" style="display:block; width:100%;">

  <div class="container" style="display:block; width:100%;">
    <h3>Request a Callback</h3>
    <form class="form-inline" action="/action_page.php">
      <label for="fullName">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullName" placeholder="Enter name" name="fullName">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
      <label for="tel">Tel:</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="tel" placeholder="Enter phone number" name="tel" required minlength="11">
      <label for="required">Service Required:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="required" placeholder="Service required" name="required" required minlength="11">
      <button>Submit</button>

    </form>
  </div>

</section>
```